# What is band storage of matrix?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, computer-science

I was asked about various storage of matrices; in particular, about band storage and other variations. I know it is something related to storage of sparse matrices in an efficient way. But, I have no clear idea about the details.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply put, a matrix is banded if all the non-zero elements are close to the diagonal. More formally, consider a matrix A whose elements are a<sub>ij</sub>. The matrix is said to be banded with bandwith m if a<sub>ij</sub> = 0 for all i, j such that abs(i-j)>=m.

A banded matrix is a sparse matrix of a very special form. Band structure is very easy to understand and operate on. Storage is efficient, and very efficient algorithms exist for banded matrices. More so than for more general sparse matrices.

Band storage takes advantage of the structure of the matrices by only storing the elements that may be non-zero.

Read more about this here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Band_matrix